# React, генерация страниц и роутинг

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Есть такой вопрос: разработываю frontend на React, все работает хорошо, как на dev сервере, так и на продакшен.

Для навигации между страницами используется Route

```
<Switch>
<AppliedRoute path="/" exact component={Home} props={childProps} />
<AppliedRoute path="/midi-editor" exact component={MidiEditor} props={childProps} />
<AppliedRoute path="/faq" exact component={Faq} props={childProps} />
<AppliedRoute path="/user-manual" exact component={UserManual} props={childProps} />
<Route component={ NotFound } />
```

;

AppliedRoute выглядит так:

```
 export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) =>
 <Route {...rest} render={props => <C {...props} {...cProps} />} />;
```

Теперь сам вопрос: выяснилось что интерфейс должен работать не только на сервере, но и просто в обычной дирректории, т.е. открываем index.html и там он должен работать, включая должен работать роутинг. Можно ли как-то ройтин переделать для такого случая или как-то из компонентов сделать статичные страницы?

Comment: _просто в обычной дирректории_ это как понимать? У вас сразу загружается все приложении, по идее просто открыв `index.html` все будет работать ( если загрузились скрипты )

Comment: и как интерфейс работает на сервере (кроме что SSR)?

Comment: @ThisMan только корнем будет не `/`, а `index.html` и ни один роут не попадет под него. Ну и браузеры могут блокировать выполнение скриптов на локальной странице

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да проблема в этом что если я открываю index.html (просто захожу в дирркторию с этим файлом и открываю, он в браузере открывается, все норм). Но если я потом пытаюсь перейти по какой-то ссылке то получаю что такого файла-пути нет. Вопрос-то в чем можно ли как-то подругому роутинги сделать или может быть можно как-то сбилдить приложение чтобы у меня было не один файл индекс, а все страницы интерфейса.

Comment: думаю, что не выйдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что вы сейчас используете апи `BrowserRouter` ([ссылка](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter))

Для того чтобы у вас все работало, надо использовать апи `HashRouter` ([ссылка](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter))

С помощью него вы сможете открывать ваш сайт как статику. Но все пути будут через `#` в `url`

Comment: Спасибо! Я проверю потом отпишусь по результатам.